# WPF Window on Winlogon Desktop

Tags: wpf, winlogon

I'm trying to show a custom Window or Control designed and built in WPF on Winlogon Desktop. I already managed, to switch the Desktop of the Thread with "SetThreadDesktop" and the Window opens on the Winlogon desktop.

The Problem is, that the content of the Window is not rendered on the Winlogon Desktop. If I open the same Window on the Default Desktop, everything works as expected.

If I replace the WPF Window with a Winforms Form, the GUI is responsive, but I want to use some of the animation features of WPF.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite why? Is this for corporate or home end user? Either way its not the best way to make friends..

Comment: The goal is to show an OnScreenKeyboard. I know there are many out there, but for 2000 workstations, it may be cheaper, to write your own...

Comment: I've tried to start my application via "psexec -x" and everything works as expected.