# Repaint window when no users are logged in

Tags: c#, windows, repaint

Is it possible to repaint a window when there are no active users logged on to a windows machine using c sharp? And will that window be available to screen capture program? Or is it not possible at all and a user must be logged into the machine.

I make use of the below:

```
SetForegroundWindow(handle);

InvalidateRect(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true);

UpdateWindow(handle);
```

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no user logged in, there is no UI running.

So, no, you can't repaint under such circumstances (there is no window to repaint).

Comment: Is there a way to force the UI to run? My app will be running as a service, does this make a difference?

Comment: @Kay - It can run as a service, but then it will still not have a UI, unless you set it up as an interactive windows service and... login to interact with it.

Comment: Hmm, I see. So its impossible for any UI to be running with no users logged in. Is there anyway around this??!

Comment: @Kay - restructure your code so it doesn't need a repaint event, or accept that a user needs to be logged in for any UI to show up. How will a screen capture program capture a screen that isn't there?

Comment: @Oded - thats not possible to be honest as the sole purpose of my app is to take screenshots of windows and save them at certain points in the day! Surely, there is something that I can do to get windows UI to keep running?!

Comment: @Kay - there are only available windows where someone is logged in. Pure and simple.

Comment: Ok, I see this isn't going to be possible - what about somehow getting the window from memory and saving it as an image without screen capturing or any need for the UI to be running?

Comment: @oded even interactive services don't show ui, they just don't die when they try to like non interactive ones do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, the logon screen is a special desktop (Windows can have several desktops). A smilar question (but not identical): [WPF Window on Winlogon Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376467/wpf-window-on-winlogon-desktop)

More information on desktops and the winlogon desktop: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hmm, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686744(v=vs.85).aspx - looks interesting. Does it mean I can get my service or app to run in a particular desktop type meaning the UI will be running?

Comment: If you place anything on the WinLogon desktop it will be displayed together with the logon screen. You will have to place your code in a service, running under the LocalSystem account to have access to the desktop.