# Capture Window as Image without Windows UI running

Tags: c#, windows, image

I've come to realise from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695235/repaint-window-when-no-users-are-logged-in) that I can not screen shot a window when there are no active users logged in.

However, I am wondering if its possible to "convert" a window into an image somehow from memory without having the Windows UI running?

Thanks all for any help.

### Update

Just to clarify, I think what needs to happen is to somehow fire off a redraw for a window and paint this to a file somehow rather than the screen. I am unsure how to event start with this though, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working with PrintWindow and firing off a WM_PRINT message. A little crude but it seems to work for now.

Answer (score 2):

You .... want to screenshot the login window? Use virtualization to make that easy

If you want to do windows-login screens yourself, implement/replace [MS GINA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742447.aspx)

If I'm not wrong, I remember using UltraVNC running as a service was able to see the login screen just fine (on XP IIRC). After loggin in, you'd have to reconnect to get a connection with the actual session 0 (console session) of the desktop. YMMV but I'd look into that.

There is pre-existing software that leverages the VNC protocol to make (remote or local) screen snapshots or screen casts.

Comment: (Added VNC reference after thinking of it)

Comment: I am hoping to capture an image from a window. This window can be notepad. I want to essentially take a screenshot of it by not relaying on windows UI to be active i.e. no users logged in.

Comment: How would there be a notepad with no users logged on. Tell me that

Comment: GINA? That was abandoned when Vista came out. It's credential providers these days.

Comment: How can you have Notepad running without people logged in? Do you mean locked?

Comment: @sehe - maybe a service running as a particular user or running as `SYSTEM` that opens notepad.

Comment: Well, if the service has access to the logon screen to display notepad, it will have access to grab the contents of that window by normal ('logged in') API. Period

Comment: @sehe - when no users are actively logged in, windows will not have its UI running. I've already tried, even if I am remoted in and I run my application and minimise the remote session, all I get are black screen shots.

Comment: I think you are defining your question to fit the answer 'No'. That said, you can only snap windows that are visible (this is a limitation everywhere on Windows).